# Passing as kwargs, reading as args - a special or temporary feature?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sometimes it's convenient to pass **kwargs** to a function which receives **args**.

For example:

```
def login( user, password ):
    ...

def write_message( author, to_user, msg ):
    ...

def http_response( action, params ):
    return globals()[ action ]( **params )

# client calls 
# http_response( 'login', { 'user': "sergzach", 'password': "PASS123" } )
```

In this schematic example, we receive information from the client and call  a function whose name is equal to the variable **action** passed in params. If our client knows the protocol {necessary 'keyword' arguments such as **user, password** for **login()** and **author, to_user, msg** for **write_message()**} then our pythonic code could be short, elegant and safe.

Is it a special (documented) or random feature?

Comment: This definitely seems like a bad idea and not safe.

Comment: @Iguananaut We can make it safe by adding a constant prefix to function names. For example, a client calls login, we add prefix msg_ and call msg_login function.

Comment: Just out of principle, don't use `globals()` like that. At least have a dedicated dictionary mapping actions to functions.

Comment: @s16h Please, give me a concrete example of secure violation which is difficult to fix in five minutes. I believe we don't need a mapping if we use prefixes for functions.

Comment: First and foremost, a five minute fix may be five minutes too late. So, that shouldn't be the way you approach an implementation. Generally, it's much harder to know, at a glance, what's currently in `globals()`. Whereas if you have a `dispatcher` dictionary mapping actions to functions then you could with a quick glance see what actions are available and what will be called for each of them. To me, it seems more elegant and readable that way.

Comment: @s16h I believe that if we worry about contains of **globals()** we could manually check that there are no objects with names beginning with a prefix 'msg_'. Easy and effective. Then we could think about probability of import the such names. Is it null? Yes, it's near. Theoretically we can make a mistake at another place (masking already imported name)  and crush the system.

Comment: @s16h Also we can use getattr() of a specific module instead of globals(), it seems very-very secure.

Comment: To be honest, my primary concern wasn't just security but readability too. I was just saying how I would do it; I still would use a dictionary. That way, adding a new actuon in the future has to explicitly happen (by not only adding it to the file but also manually adding it to the dispatcher dictionary); it avoids accidents and improves readability. This is only my opinion :) I'm not saying yours is wrong; just wanted to share my perspective with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python distinguishes between *arguments* and *parameters*.

A *parameter* is something you list in the function definition:

```
def foo(bar, baz=default, **quux):
    pass
```

An *argument* is something you pass to a function when you call it:

```
result = foo(bar, baz, **quux)
```

Given the above function definition, Python allows any of these calls:

```
foo(bar, baz, quux1=quux1, quux2=quux2)
foo(*(bar, baz), quux1=quux1, quux2=quux2)
foo(**{'bar': bar, 'baz': baz, 'quux1': quux1, 'quux2':quux2})
```

They're all perfectly legal and do the same thing.  That is, they all pass the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is guaranteed to work in python. In python, you can always choose to pass named parameters as keyword arguments.

As already pointed out in the comments, this approach is potentially not safe (calling a function by a user-provided name). So pay extra care if doing so (the comments also include some good suggestions for safety).

Other than that, I'm not sure I understand what exactly you mean by "a random feature"?..

Comment: I mean: is it probably temporary functionality or it will be supported for a long time?